# Bootstrap date picker after selecting date not closing picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

After selecting date from bootstrap date picker the picker popup is not hiding. What may be the issue?

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/329suzv9/7/)

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon flat">
                <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input name="DATEFROM" id="dateFrom" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    orientation: "top"
  });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add **autoclose: true** in datepicker function. 
The new jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   orientation: "top",
   autoclose: true
});

});
```

Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/329suzv9/8/

Comment: I didn't see that option in the documentation. nice.

Comment: Some example of datepicker functionalities can be found  [here](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox). Mark the **radio button** or **checkbox** to see the code below.

Answer (score 2):

Simply hide the datapicker in the changedate event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    orientation: "top"
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#dateFrom').datepicker('hide');
  });

});
```